# What does the square brackets mean in a Typescript type definition?

Tags: typescript

I have the following Typescript code:

```
export type MyType = {
  stuff1?: {
    [stuff2: string]: Stuff3;
  };
}
```

What does this mean?

I understand that this is defining a type `MyType` and it is an object with optional key `stuff1`. The type of `stuff1` is itself an object.

But what does that sub-object look like? I know that sub-object has one key-value pair. And the value of that pair is of type `Stuff3`. But what does `[stuff2: string]` mean in this context?

Comment: As far as I know it is just the definition of the dictionary key. So you have a dictionary with a key of type `string` and `Stuff3` value.

Comment: So it's just saying that `stuff2` is a string literal?